# How to custom mapping fields name or type for method MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I used the method MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize() to deserialize from MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument to MyType. But the method always meet System.FormatException since fields in MyType are not 100% match to the fields in BsonDocument.

I've tried to convert a complex json object(let's called mobj) from MongoDB(query result) to C# object(let's called csobj), so that I could deal with the data. The defualt datatype in csobj I use is string. But the mobj is too complex and we know it's schema less.

Once meet datatype like BinData(0,""), BinData(1,""), BinData(2,""), ISODate("") etc, in mobj, the System.FormatException may happen.

Once there are extra new fields in mobj, the System.FormatException may happen.

Once there are space in the field name like "Page one" : "XXXX", the the System.FormatException may happen and I don't know how to fix it till now.

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://xxxxxx");
var database = client.GetDatabase("xxxxxxxxxx");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("xxxxxxxxxx");

var results = await collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(filterBsonDocumentArray).ToListAsync();

foreach (var doc in results)
{
    var model = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(doc); // always meet exception here
}
```

Exception examples:

(mongodb datatype could not map with string)

System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class MongoQueryDemo.MyType: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Binary'. ---> System.FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Binary'.

(_id in mongo could not found UserId in C# object auto)

System.FormatException: Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class MongoQueryDemo.MyType.

My questions are list here:

1. Is there any way to tell the Deserializer, please be case insensitive;
2. Is there any way to customize the mapping the field name from mobj to csobj, like define "_id" --> UserId, "Ip Addr" --> "IpAddr";
3. Is there any way to customize the datatype, let the datatype BinData(0,""), BinData(1,""), BinData(2,""), ISODate("") are all could be convert into string without System.FormatException;
4. Is there any way to dealing whole complex sub-object mapping to C# string regardless its fields? Since its dynamic in schema less mongodb and I could not predefine any unknown field in the sub-ojbects.

Comment: If the whole table is schema less, why bother deserialize the first place? Use it as `BsonDocument`, and you can read from it like `.GetValue("<insert column name here>")`, or use `database.GetCollectino<dynamic>`.

Comment: Hello, not whole but partially. I've alreay create C# object and most of feilds seems deserialize with no exception and it working properly sometimes, except there are some dynamic sub-object be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute will map field names from mobj to csojo                  `[BsonElement(@"52WeekChange")]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe give an example of how to use the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, which are explored [here, in the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/). (The following examples come from there.)

You can use a `ClassMap`:

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.SomeProperty);
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.AnotherProperty);
});
```

If you prefer to define mappings in your c# type declaration, you can use attributes.

**BsonContructor** can be used to map properties during object construction:

```cs
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  // You can use this on one or more overloads as well:
  [BsonConstructor]
  public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

**BsonElement** is a property-level solution:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    // The first parameter ("sp") is an optional mongodb field name mapping.
    [BsonElement("sp")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```